# Play full spotify track inside my own website using spotify web api for free or not

Tags: spotify, spotify-docker-client

Currently, I've registered a spotify account. I want to use my own player to play Spotify track, with controls: pause, seek, play. Spotify provides Web Playback SDK but it is restricted for premium account only, if use embeded widget then it only play 30s and can't seek. Do you have any suggestion for this problem?

Comment: Getting the premium account could solve the problem, right?!?